# Bode Fano criterium and low Q-factor

Tags: rf, microwave, matching

I am currently studying the [Bode-Fano criterium](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227742095_Bode_and_Fano_Impedance_Matching) and how it can be used to design wideband amplifiers.

It's stated that a low load Q-factor (high resistive component with respect to the imaginary one) leads to a lower achievable reflection coefficient.
Taking a look at the criterium for a parallel RC load:

$$\left\lvert\int_0^\infty\ln\frac{1}{\left\lvert\Gamma(\omega)\right\rvert} d\omega\lt\frac{\pi}{RC}\right\rvert$$

I don't understand how, from this equation, does it follow that the minimum reflection coefficient can be achieved only in the presence of a low-Q load. (So, I consider high R and low C.)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your idea of what the Q of  the parallel rc is. 

In a parallel rc, the Q goes up as the r goes up. 


In a series rc the Q goes down as the r goes up. 


This Q stuff is a little confusing unless you are talking about resonant circuits.

Comment: @user69795 Thanks for the reply. When you say that in a parallel rc the Q increases for increasing R, the same should not be true for the capacitance C? But, in that case, we would increase the load imaginary component. I see a contradiction and I don't understand where I'm doing wrong

Comment: Yes, I think that increasing C also increases the “Q”.  One way of thinking about it, is that a parallel Rc is like a tuned circuit resonating at DC.  As either r or c gets bigger, the bandwidth drops...narrow bandwidth implies higher Q.